# Ubuntu 12.04 update requires Lubuntu 13.04 CD/DVD

Tags: updates

Running 12.04 and have been applying updates when notified by Update Manager.  Up until now the updates have always been applied with no issues. With the latest update, the process stops and a message is displayed

> CD/DVD 'Lubuntu 13.04_Raring Ringtail_-Release i385 (20130423.1)' is required.  Please insert the above CD/DVD into the drive 'media/cdrom' to install software packages from it.

I could download and burn a 13.04 Lubuntu ISO and follow the instructions in the message, but something is not right here.  That is, if I am running 12.04 Ubuntu, why would an update require Lubuntu 13.04?  Has anyone seen this same issue?

Comment: Please add the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the sources file

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment (put a `#` at the beginning of) the line containing `deb cdrom`. Save the  file and try again.

Comment: Thank you K.K, that solved the problem.   I wonder, though, why the issue did not occur on any of the previous updates that I applied.  I did not modify that file previously, so I am thinking it must be a bug that was introduced in a previous update.  Have you heard of the problem and source before?

Comment: Ya, I experienced

Comment: Done, marked accepted. thanks again.  Also, apologies to @Braiam for not replying. Somehow, I did not see your request from Aug 5 until just now.  It was there, of course, but I did not notice it.