# software install/update requires CD

Tags: drive

when i try to install pip-python 
i get this message
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 13.10 *Saucy Salamander* - Release amd64 (20131016.1)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter

i don't have cdrom ?
Any possibility to have a copy of os in local disk,external HDD for this problem?
I need the solution to this problem
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/328864/ubuntu-12-04-update-requires-lubuntu-13-04-cd-dvd

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and may be you will find CD-ROM listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Launch "Software & Updates" from the Unity Dash.  On the "Ubuntu Software" tab, make sure "Cdrom with Ubuntu..." is not checked.